# how can I access a variable defined in one controller from the scope of another controller?

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-scope

I have the following controllers: 
`HeaderCtrl`, `NewsFeedCtrl`, `MainCtrl`

`MainCtrl` contains both the other two controllers, which are in the same level.

I'm defining an object in `authenticationService` and update its value in `MainCtrl` and I update it frequently in `NewsFeedCtrl` and I want to display its value in the HTML page controlled by `HeaderCtrl`.

when I use this line in my `HeaderCtrl`:

```
$scope.unreadNum=authenticationService.notificationList.length;
```

and then I use data binding in my HTML page to display its value:

```
{{unreadNum}}
```

I only get the initial value I inserted in `authenticationService`, not the one after the update in the other controllers.
it seems that my `HeaderCtrl` is defining all his scope objects only one time and then there's no more use for the Ctrl, but I still want his HTML page to be updated after the update in object values in other controllers.

to sum it up: the value of the object I want is stored in one of my services, and I am unable to display it in my HTML page because I can't seem bind it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send messages between the controllers using a service.  The service looks something like this...

```
aModule.factory('messageService', function ($rootScope) {

var sharedService = {};

sharedService.message = {};

sharedService.prepForBroadcast = function(msg) {
    this.message = msg;
    this.broadcastItem();
};

sharedService.broadcastItem = function () {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast');
};

return sharedService;
});
```

In the controller that is sending the message, inject this service...

```
aModule.controller("sendingController", function ($scope, messageService) {
```

Then add a method that will broadcast the change to any controller that is listening...

```
   $scope.sendMessage = function (someObject) {
        messageService.prepForBroadcast(someObject);
    },
```

In any controller that wants to receive the message, inject the service, and add a handler like this to do something with the message...

```
  $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
       //update what you will..
       $scope.something = messageService.message;
   });
```