# Angular - Update parent $scope from child window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, window.opener

Here is the problem I am trying to solve.

I have a `window.open` function open a small window for the user to login/signup with a social network of their choice. Once the user is logged in, I want the small window to close and for the original parent window's `$scope` to update without having to refresh the page.

My whole goal of this is to not interrupt the user's experience of the site. The site is a music site so if the user is listening to a song and the page reloads, they will lose their spot in the site and ultimately be unhappy.

I think that's all.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', [

  $scope.loginTrigger = function() {
    window.open("http://www.url.com/login", "_blank", "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, top=0, left=100, width=1000, height=600");
  }

  if ($location.hash()) {
     $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/users/oauth_complete/',
      data: data,
     }).success(function(data){
        if(!data.success){
         $window.location.href = '/usersetup';
        }else {
         $scope.LoggedInUser = data;
         storage.set('LoggedInUser', data);

         //Here is my current code: Small window closes and the parent page reloads but I don't want to use refresh as it will interrupt the user experience.
         window.close();
         window.opener.location.reload();
        }
     },"JSON");
  };

}]);
```

Comment: You need to send a message to the parent window's controller that something exciting has happened, then it can do what it needs to do. Code examples for messaging here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27196693/how-can-i-access-a-variable-defined-in-one-controller-from-the-scope-of-another/27196982#27196982

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure I follow your post. I currently have all the code in the same controller. Reason being is so once the the user clicks the "Connect to XYZ" button on my site, it will redirect to the URI I designate, but with a hash at the end of the url but that is why I have the if(hash) code in the main controller--- the user could be on any page. I tried getting it work with a factory, but failed. As an example, this is essentially what I am trying to accomplish... https://oauth.io/signup (oauth window pops up, user authorizes, then window hides and page updates without reload)

Answer (score 0):

You can 'talk' between classes using $emit and $on

In your login controller, you would use $emit.

```
$scope.$emit('eventName', myData);
```

Then in your other controller, you would listen using the $on function:

```
$scope.$on('eventName', function(event, data) { console.log(data); });
```